# How to fix my data collection program?

Tags: java

This program is meant to collect data on the speed of three search algorithms (linear, binary, and random). I've extensively tested each search method called and they all work. I know the error exists in the for loop containing k, but I'm not sure what or why. I get the proper results for linear[0], binary[0], and random[0], but cannot get an answer for any other place in the arrays within the loop (which makes sense since I the other places have not happened yet). Outside of the loop though, I can't print out any part of any of the arrays.

```
import java.util.Random;
/*class to generate testing data*/
public class GenerateData{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*creates and runs through each power of 2 array*/
    for(int i=3; i < 5; i++) {
        /*calculates a power of 2 starting at 8*/
        int n = (int)Math.pow(2, i);
        /*creates an array of a power of 2 starting at 8*/
        int [] test = new int[n];
        /*generates a starting testing point for the array*/
        int start = 3;
        /*fills the array with sorted testing data*/
        for(int j=0; j < n; j++) {
        test[j] = start;
        start = start + 2;
        }
        /*creates an array to store linear testing times*/
        long [] linear = new long[10];
        /*creates an array to store binary testing times*/
        long [] binary = new long[10];
        /*creates an array to store random testing times*/
        long [] random = new long[10];
        /*runs through the search algorithms ten times*/
        for(int k=0; k < 10; k++) {
        /*generates a random number to test no larger than the largest 
          value in the array*/
        int queryValue = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(start-1));
        /*tests the array in each algorithm, keeping track of start and
          end time*/
        long linearStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        int linearTest = LinearSearch.linearSearch(queryValue, test);
        /*calculates the time for linear algorithm and adds it to
         an array keeping track of linear algorithm run times*/
        linear[k] = System.nanoTime() - linearStartTime;
        long binaryStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        int binaryTest = BinarySearch.binarySearch(queryValue, test);
        /*calculates the time for binary algorithm and adds it to
         an array keeping track of binary algorithm run times*/
        binary[k] = System.nanoTime() - binaryStartTime;
        long randomStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        int randomTest = RandomSearch.randomSearch(queryValue, test);
        /*calculates the time for random algorithm and adds it to
          an array keeping track of random algorithm run times*/
        random[k] = System.nanoTime() - randomStartTime;
        }
        /*placeholder initial values for mins, maxes, and avgs*/
        long linMin = linear[1];
        long binMin = binary[1];
        long randMin = random[1];
        long linMax = linear[1];
        long binMax = binary[1];
        long randMax = random[1];
        long linAvg = 0;
        long binAvg = 0;
        long randAvg = 0;
         /*cycles through the arrays calculating the min, max, and avg*/
        for(int l=0; l < 9; l++) {
        /*calculates the avg for each algorithm array*/
        linAvg = linAvg + linear[l] / 2;
        binAvg = binAvg + binary[l] / 2;
        randAvg = randAvg + random[l] / 2;
        /*calculates the min for each algorithm array*/
        if(linear[l] < linMin) {
            linMin = linear[l];
        }
        if(binary[l] < binMin) {
            binMin = binary[l];
        }
        if(random[l] < randMin) {
            randMin = random[l];
        }
        /*calculates the max for each algorithm array*/
        if(linear[l] > linMax) {
            linMax = linear[l];
        }
        if(binary[l] > binMax) {
            binMax = linear[l];
        }
        if(random[l] > randMax) {
            randMax = random[l];
        }
        /*prints the current power of 2, min, max, and avg
          for each algorithm into a file*/
        StdOut.println("linear" + "," + n + "," + linMin + "," + linMax + "," + linAvg);
        StdOut.println("binary" + "," + n + "," + binMin + "," + binMax + "," + binAvg);
        StdOut.println("random" + "," + n + "," + randMin + "," + randMax + "," + randAvg);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

The binary search I'm using. Provided for testing purposes.

```
/*class containing binary search algorithm*/
public class BinarySearch {
    /*conducts a binary search as specified by user*/
    public static int binarySearch(int queryValue, int[] list) {
    int length = list.length; 
    /*last point of list*/
    int top = length-1;       
    /*first point of list*/
    int bottom = 0;    
    /*starting midpoint of list*/
    int mid = (int)Math.round((top + bottom)/2);
    /*binary search*/
    do {
        if(queryValue > list[mid]) {
         bottom = mid;
         mid = (int)Math.ceil((top + bottom) / 2.0);
        }
        else {
         top = mid;
         mid = (int)Math.floor((top + bottom) / 2.0);
        }
        if(queryValue == list[mid]) {
        return mid;
        }
    } while (mid < top || mid > bottom);
    /*returns -1 if user value not found*/
    return -1;
    }
}
```

The linear search I'm using. Provided for testing purposes.

```
/*class containing linear search algorithm*/
public class LinearSearch {
    public static int linearSearch(int queryValue, int[] list) {
    int length = list.length;
    /*conducts a linear search as specified by user*/
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if((int)queryValue == (int)list[i]) {
        return i;
        }
    }
    /*return -1 if user value not found*/
    return -1; 
    }
}
```

The random search I'm using. Provided for testing purposes.

```
import java.util.Random;
/*class containing random search algorithm*/
public class RandomSearch {
    public static int randomSearch(int queryValue, int[] list) {
    /*conducts a random search as specified by user*/
    /*trys 10,000,000 random combinations searching
      for user value*/
    int length = list.length;
    for(int i=0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        /*generates a random number from 0 to length*/
        int randomNum = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(length));
        if((int)queryValue == (int)list[randomNum]) {
         return randomNum;
        }
    }
    /*returns -2 if user value not found*/
    return -2;
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't a compilation error. The program just runs without ever printing out any data. Using print statements, I was able to isolate the error to the for loop using k. The binary, linear, and random arrays print out 0 for each place in their respective arrays.

Comment: Please add that information, and anything else you've learned, to your question.

Comment: I've added the search algorithms I'm using, so anyone else can test GenerateData as well.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Java, you want to use
System.out.println(....)
not your StdOut....

Comment: I have StdOut and StdIn saved in the same directory, so they work.

Comment: The normal Java names for the input stream is System.out, not StdOut. I have no idea what you mean by "have StdOut saved..."

Comment: I'm using the programs from http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/StdOut.java and http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/StdOut.java

Comment: easy test: try it my way, see if it helps. Will tell you something no matter what the result is

Comment: I've tried it both ways. The results are the same. The StdOut and StdIn operations work as long as the two files are saved in the same directory as where they are being used/called.